# Filtering out duplicates while retaining all join data with MySQL/Laravel Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

I'm developing a Movie tracking app in Laravel and I'm currently stuck trying to join `Ratings` on `Movies`, although I think I'm almost there I just don't know how to get exactly to where I want to be.

Here's my current working query (using `->toSql()` but it's an eloquent query in my app):

```
SELECT 
    `movies`.*,
    `ratings`.`user`,
    `ratings`.`favorite`,
    `ratings`.`created_at` AS `rating_created_at`,
    `ratings`.`updated_at` AS `rating_updated_at`,
    `users`.`id` AS `user_id`,
    `users`.`name` AS `user_name`
FROM
    `movies`
        INNER JOIN
    `ratings` ON `movies`.`tmdb_id` = `ratings`.`tmdb_id`
        INNER JOIN
    `users` ON `ratings`.`user` = `users`.`id`
WHERE
    `ratings`.`favorite` = 1
GROUP BY `ratings`.`tmdb_id`
ORDER BY `ratings`.`created_at` DESC
```

Here's the problem with it:

Its output displays duplicate movies for each movie that has a matching ratings row since multiple people can favorite a movie: `ratings.user`.

What I'd like:

- Display a favorited movie once
- Be able to know who favorited that movie via the `ratings.user` column and display their name with the movie
- In the case that multiple users have favorited the same movie have the ability to still access all user data

Where I'm confused is how to be able to grab all of the user data associated with a given movie without duplicating its return.

**Edit**: I updated my SQL query to include the users table so I can access their names, but specifically bullet point 3 above is still an issue.

Comment: In trying to come up with a solution to this I've read more about pivot tables, is that how I should be doing this? It would mean a database restructure.

Answer (score 0):

You should use laravel collection to filter the results.
I'll provide with the code I worked with

```
public function getData_propertyById_Method($id){
    $data = DB::table('property_management')
        ->select(
            'property_management.*',
            'property_categories.title as category_title',
            'property_images.image_file',
            'property_images.title as image_title',
            'floor_plan_images.title as plan_title',
            'floor_plan_images.image_file as plan_image_file',
        )
        ->leftJoin('property_categories', 'property_categories.id', '=', 'property_management.category_id')
        ->leftJoin('property_images', 'property_images.property_id', '=', 'property_management.id')
        ->leftJoin('floor_plan_images', 'floor_plan_images.property_id', '=', 'property_management.id')
        ->where('property_management.id', $id)
        ->distinct()
        ->get();

    if ($data->isEmpty()) {
        return null; // Return null if no data found
    }

    // Extract property details
    $propertyDetails = $data->first();
    $property = [
        'id' => $propertyDetails->id,
        'title' => $propertyDetails->title,
        'slug' => $propertyDetails->slug,
        'type_id' => $propertyDetails->type_id,
        'category_id' => $propertyDetails->category_id,
        'price' => $propertyDetails->price,
        'youtube_code' => $propertyDetails->youtube_code,
        'area' => $propertyDetails->area,
        'location' => $propertyDetails->location,
        'city_id' => $propertyDetails->city_id,
        'state_id' => $propertyDetails->state_id,
        'latitude' => $propertyDetails->latitude,
        'longitude' => $propertyDetails->longitude,
        'description' => $propertyDetails->description,
        'highlights_ids' => $propertyDetails->highlights_ids,
        'status' => $propertyDetails->status,
        'created_by' => $propertyDetails->created_by,
        'updated_by' => $propertyDetails->updated_by,
        'created_at' => $propertyDetails->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $propertyDetails->updated_at,
        'category_title' => $propertyDetails->category_title,
    ];

    // Group images by property ID and remove duplicates
    $images = $data->groupBy('id')->map(function ($group) {
        return $group->unique('image_file')->map(function ($item) {
            return [
                'image_file' => $item->image_file,
                'image_title' => $item->image_title
            ];
        });
    });

    // Group floor plans by property ID and remove duplicates
    $floorPlans = $data->groupBy('id')->map(function ($group) {
        return $group->unique('plan_image_file')->map(function ($item) {
            return [
                'plan_title' => $item->plan_title,
                'plan_image_file' => $item->plan_image_file
            ];
        });
    });

    // Combine property details with images and floor plans
    $property['images'] = $images->get($id, []);
    $property['floor_plans'] = $floorPlans->get($id, []);

    $property = collect($property);

    return $property;
}
```